# Button click, run a php function with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, safari

I want to run my php function when I click on this button, This works fine on Chrome and Firefox, But not on Safari, I don't know why :( Please help me...

My PHP Function is :  complete_automate_xml();
My Button is : `<button id="btn" onclick="alertWithoutNotice();" class="deletebtn button button-next">Verstuur E-mails</button>`
My Code is :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#btn').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../wp-admin/admin.php?page=spd_xml_importer',
            data: {action: 'call_this'},
            success: function (html) {
                alert(html);
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
<div class="email-bt">
    <script>function alertWithoutNotice(message) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('E-mails zijn verzonden');
            }, 300);
        }</script>
        <button id="btn" onclick="alertWithoutNotice();" class="deletebtn button button-next">Verstuur E-mails</button>
</div>
<?php
if ($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
    complete_automate_xml();
}
```

Comment: is there any js errors in safari in console?

Comment: Nothing :( But it wont run the php when i click the button,, very strange

Comment: seems strange to have one inline function and one attached via the `onload` handler - two competing functions almost. Could you combine the two?

Comment: will do:)  and I will post in belowe, as an answer, please refer if you have a free time <3 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i was thinking more like this - but I'm not 100% sure this is the issue with Safari I just wondered whether there was confusion in the browser as to which function to invoke.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('E-mails zijn verzonden');
        }, 300);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../wp-admin/admin.php?page=spd_xml_importer',
            data: { action: 'call_this' },
            success: function (html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<div class="email-bt">
        <button id="btn" class="deletebtn button button-next">Verstuur E-mails</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot,
But unfortunately it also doesn't work, Perfect with Chrome but not with Safari :(

Comment: sadly I do not have Safari to test with - so I don't even know if Safari has a console to help debug with. Does the click trigger anything at all in Safari?

Comment: It's okay friend :) GLad you tried to help alot. Yes it does have a console, JS are working nicely though $_POST does not when it comes to there. 

Anyhow i just want to run that php function when the user click Button..

Comment: Just fount the issue with the console, AJAX  wont run properly, Issue is with the Ajax